# Function within For Loop Not returning correct value

Tags: python, list

I have an issue, and its regarding a for loop, list (appending / removing).

Here is the list:

```
L = ['Josh', 'started:', '14:39', '8305955', 'frenchs', '10', '8305955-fr001', '8305955-fr002', '8305955-fr003', '8305955-fr004', '8305955-fr005', 'ended:', '14:39']
```

When I run the below code.

```
D = "-fr"
E = []
for i in L:
    if D not in i:
        L.remove(i)
    else:
        E.append(i)
```

`L[6]` is removed, and not appended into List E.
List E should return the below, but the first index is missing.

```
E = ['8305955-fr001', '8305955-fr002', '8305955-fr003', '8305955-fr004', '8305955-fr005']
```

Comment: Yeah you probably shouldn’t modify the list while iterating over it - try writing it out using for loops and see if it starts doing what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't modify a list while iterating over it. A simple way to solve this issue is iterating over a copy by slicing it:

```
for i in L[:]:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of the list while iterating over it using copy.copy (https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

```
import copy
L = ['Josh', 'started:', '14:39', '8305955', 'frenchs', '10', '8305955-fr001', '8305955-fr002', '8305955-fr003', '8305955-fr004', '8305955-fr005', 'ended:', '14:39']

copy_L = copy.copy(L)
D = "-fr"
E = []
for i in copy_L:
    if D not in i:
        L.remove(i)
    else:
        E.append(i)

print(E)
#['8305955-fr001', '8305955-fr002', '8305955-fr003', '8305955-fr004', '8305955-fr005']
```